# apache2 + Passenger3 + Rails3 routing problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, apache

Having a problem with passenger 3

in routes.rb i have

match   'main/subgroups/:id' =>  'main#subgroups'

And in access_log file

"GET /main/subgroups/Arts HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" 
"GET /main/subgroups/Arts%2FCrafts%2FNeedlework HTTP/1.1" 404 323 "-"

As I understand Apache does not pass the second request to passenger.

What should I change in httpd.conf?

Comment: This was an apache issue.
AllowEncodedSlashes On 
was an issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the second URL is not matching the route since your 'id' field has forward slashes in it, which is a delimiter for rails routes.

In order to make this work try changing your route to (Note the * instead of the : on id):

```
match 'main/subgroups/*id' => 'main#subgroups'
```

That should ensure that everything after main/subgroups is set into params[:id] regardless of it's contents.

Comment: This is not rails problem as I understand. Requests containing extra slashes are not even passed to rails by apache